# Programmatically change crystal report formulas

Tags: crystal-reports

I was wondering if it is possible to change formulas of a crystal report programmatically. I want to list all formulas of a report in my web app and give the user the possibility to modify them.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

namespace Craft
{
    class Mate
    {
        Order_Print _r = new Order_Print();

        void Preview()
        {
            foreach (FormulaFieldDefinition f in _r.DataDefinition.FormulaFields)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(f.Name);

                f.Text = InputBox.Show("Input the formula for " + f.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for example we use the follwoing function to change formulas:

```
 Public Sub SetReportFormulaContents(ByRef Report As ReportDocument, ByVal FormulaName As String, ByVal FormulaContents As String)
    Dim Formula As FormulaFieldDefinition = Nothing

    ' Get the ReportObject by name and cast it as a FieldObject
    If TypeOf (Report.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item(FormulaName)) Is CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormulaFieldDefinition Then
        Formula = Report.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item(FormulaName)
        Formula.Text = FormulaContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to change whether the syntax of the formula is Crystal or Basic? Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386710/how-to-programmatically-change-a-crystal-reports-formula-from-crystal-syntax-to-b