# C# Crystal Reports TimeZone

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports, timezone

I am using Crystal Reports ReportDocument object to load, run, and export a report to PDF.  The report time is that of the web server.  We have users running reports from different time zones.  Is there a way to set the time zone of the report?

```
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(job.sproc, con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> p in sprParams)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.Key, p.Value);
                }

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

                ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
                rpt.Load(Path.Combine(RPT_LOCATION, job.repFileName));
                rpt.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);

                int i = 1;
                foreach (string subReport in job.subReports)
                {
                    using (ReportDocument srpt = rpt.OpenSubreport(subReport))
                    {
                        srpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[i++]);
                    }

                }

                ParameterFieldDefinitions parmFields = rpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
                ParameterValues pvals = new ParameterValues();
                foreach (ParameterFieldDefinition def in parmFields)
                {
                    if (!def.IsLinked())
                    {
                        ParameterDiscreteValue pval = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
                        if (rptParams.ContainsKey(def.Name))
                        {
                            pval.Value = rptParams[def.Name];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            switch (def.ParameterValueKind)
                            {
                                case ParameterValueKind.BooleanParameter:
                                    pval.Value = false;
                                    break;
                                case ParameterValueKind.CurrencyParameter:
                                    pval.Value = 0;
                                    break;
                                case ParameterValueKind.DateParameter:
                                    pval.Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                                    break;
                                case ParameterValueKind.DateTimeParameter:
                                    pval.Value = DateTime.Now;
                                    break;
                                case ParameterValueKind.NumberParameter:
                                    pval.Value = 0;
                                    break;
                                case ParameterValueKind.TimeParameter:
                                    pval.Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    pval.Value = String.Empty;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        pvals.Add(pval);
                        def.ApplyCurrentValues(pvals);
                    }
                }

                //save file
                job.fileName = ExfiltrateReport(rpt, exfilType);
                job.created = DateTime.UtcNow;
                rpt.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: Check this http://www.bogge.info/blog/scripting/changeing-timezone-in-crystal-reports/

Comment: We have hundreds of reports with the print time in the header. I want to do this in C# for all reports.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656713/programmatically-change-crystal-report-formulas

Comment: You could do it in the source data before it goes to the reporting engine.  Please show some code and we might be able to advise further.

Comment: You could try [UflTimeZone](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/products/ufltimezone/).  Full disclosure: I wrote and sell it.